# Unable to run Windows 10 installer from usb stick. Possible hardware issue

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb

I have a PC at home that worked fine for 2 years with its current hardware setup with Windows 7. While I was away users of this PC reported some errors randomly showing up (they don't remember details, it was in 2015), overall slowness and afterwards it just stopped booting into Windows. Now it just endlessly sits on Windows logo (it doesn't load to Safe mode dialog).
Hardware:
Asus Sabertooth FX990 R2.0.
AMD FX-8350.
2x8 Gb of ECC memory.
760W power supply from Seasonic, this model can handle up to 900W in peak.
Several SSD and HDD. Big heatsink on cpu.
Nothing was overclocked. SSDs had a lot of resource left.
Memtest86 doesn't report any errors. Motherboard has several LEDs that turn on when respective component has failed completely (cpu, memory, video, bridge etc.) and they doesn't turn on.

Now the problem - when I try to load Windows 10 installer from usb or dvd it just doesn't load. I see it in the bios (UEFI), PC starts booting from it (it doesn't report that "no bootable device" was found) and then it fails - either on Windows 10 blue logo, or it shows logo and spinner, or it shows purple screen with no text etc. I tried 2 different usb stcks and one dvd (with win7), and tried different windows images - nothing works in this PC. Usb sticks  do work in other PCs though.

Where do I even start to solve this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you start? You start with standard procedure, by simplifying things.

1. Remove all unnecessary SSDs and HDDs. Leave only one SSD, for the system. Check this SSD if it ever works, using a different computer with either SATA, or with USB external enclosure at least. If fails, use a regular SATA HDD.
2. reset BIOS to factory defaults;
3. Have a SATA DVD disk reader installed;
4. Start a stand-alone Microsoft Memory test, not some 30-years old amateur benchmark;
5. Monitor power consumption of your PC using Kill-a-Watt monitor; watch for hot spots on mainboard.
6. If the MS memory test passes several times, try to install something like [Knoppix](http://download.cnet.com/Knoppix/3000-18513_4-75186118.html) from your DVD-CDfrom. Or [Hiren's universal boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd). Or any other stand-alone bottable CD. like anti-virus emergency boot disk, or else.
7. If it boots normally, proceed with windows installation; start with Win7.
8. If Win7 installs, you can try Win10, but there is no guarantee with hardware compatibility.
9. Forget USB, and good luck.